# Java - Is this a correct way of writing a single super-class with multiple sub-classes which implements a single interface?

Tags: java

I'm trying grasp the concept of interfaces by an example simple as possible that came through my mind after already having these classes. So I began sub-classing each other after reading a bit about inheritance and interfaces, then decided that Person should be my super-class in this case. I think this is completely wrong but I am not sure how much wrong is in it?

The interface:

```
public interface BasicAgenda 
{   
    //Person super-class
    public String getName();
    public String getPhoneNumber();
    public void setName(String name);
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);



    //Event sub-class of Person
    public String getBirthDay();
    public String getMeeting();
    public String getDebate();
    public void setBirthDay(String birthDay);
    public void setMeeting(String meeting);
    public void setDebate(String debate);


    //Time sub-class of Event
    public int getSecond();
    public int getMinute();
    public int getHour();
    public void setSecond(int second);
    public void setMinute(int minute);
    public void setHour(int hour);
    public void setTime(int second, int minute, int hour);
    public void nextSecond();


    //MyDate sub-class of Time
    public int getYear();
    public int getMonth();
    public int getDay();
    public void setYear(int year);
    public void setMonth(int month);
    public void setDay(int day);
    public void setDate(int day, int year, int month);
}
```

Classes:

```
public class Person
{ 
     //some code here and there 
}

public class Event extends Person 
{
     //some code here and there
}


public class Time extends Event
{
     /some code here and there
}


public class MyDate extends Time implements BasicAgenda
{
     //some code here and there
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So ... you're saying an Event is-a Person? And a Time Is-A Person? And every instance of a BasicAgenda, of any class, has all the methods for any subclass of BasicAgenda?

Comment: @AndyThomas And `MyDate` is both a person **and** an agenda!

Comment: @AndyThomas I guess so

Comment: Don't know to study properly, probably must be the problem I think etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a class `A` extends a class `B` then it means the developer intentds that *object of class `B` **behaves** like `A`*. You typically extend a class when you see there is a common base class which can hold common code and then the sub classes can **extend** the behavior of parent base class by adding more methods. Also some times a sub class can **override** some behavior of its parent class. This way sub classes need not re write that common part. [Tip : do not use inheritance just to prevent code duplicacy, instead see if there is a relation of *behaves like*, some text says *is a* relationship].

You declare the interface as a contract declaration to other developers that your class will certainly provide implementation for the declared contract. It also keeps your code less coupled to the concrete logic and you can freely modify the concrete logic without affecting the dependent code. Your other classes depend just on the declared interface.

Ideally in Object oriented language code looks like a **Lego block game**. A class exposes its interface for which it provides the implementation, while other classes consume this interface (as composition). Both the implementing class and the dependent classes are dependent upon pure abstraction rather than concrete classes.

Above were few important tips which you can dive deep and learn. Other important keywords for you : Encapsulation. It protects your state. Hide state of your class. It shall protect you and others from direct access of your state. In future you can add rules and logoc which shall enable you to put easy checks and do logical pre or/and post processing once there is an attempt to modify the state.

Dupicate code is a sin, Avoid it try seeing if you can use composition and reuse what is already written, may be you can wrap what is already written with some additional logoc. You can extend what is already written. Choose option after giving thought.

Most important : write code. Do mistakes, read, correct your mistakes. Learn refactoring, its hard to master it but for sure you will enjoy it. All the best and happy learning.

Answer (score 3):

Most definitely wrong.  I see far too much repetition and lack of encapsulation here.  This is not a good use of inheritance.

Why do you need a custom date and time class?  Wrong from beginning to end.

An `Event` is not a `Person`.

You are confusing inheritance and composition.

You are using String in a number of spots that suggest a custom class for better encapsulation.

I don't know your requirements, but here's an alternative idea:

```
public class Person { 
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate birthdate;
    private List<Event> events;
    // You add the rest 
}

public class Event {
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime start;
    // You add the rest
}
```

You have `Meeting` and `Debate` in your question.  Maybe your `Event` needs an enumeration of types.

No need for any inheritance.  It's all HAS-A: composition.

Comment: It is just for study purposes, I am not trying to re-invent the wheel or something

Comment: Study purposes?  That's even worse.  Why learn how to design badly?

Comment: For the sake of using an interface, is probably extremely badly

Comment: Those classes is what i had and tried to make an interfaces of them

Comment: It's much, much worse than that.

Comment: You aren't getting it.  Your classes are bad, too.  All that repetition of day, month, year, etc.?  The JDK 8 time package does it better than you ever will.  Learn how to use what's already been given to you.

Comment: Damn it man, damn it, I thought this time will be better, anyway you are right! Thanks